# Reading GeoTiff using .NET

Tags: .net, geotiff-tiff

Is there a managed library for reading the coordinates from a [geotiff](http://trac.osgeo.org/geotiff/) file in .NET ?

I know it can be done thru GDAL, but I am looking for a **[managed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code)** alternative.

Comment: You could use Manifold: http://www.manifold.net, but you would need at least their runtime to distribute with your application. You would have to read the GeoTIFF as a Manifold component before querying from it though, which may be a no go for you. 

It's all managed VC++ under the hood, and their GeoTIFF reader is written by them. You can test with VBScript or C# scripts inside the application, and then port to an external app in C# or whatever.

Comment: otherwise the mapwindow api might be useful, I'm sure there's others too which I'll post if I remember

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How bout [libtiff.net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [GDAL included .NET wrappers](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp).  This allows you to access any of the GDAL functionality from within managed code.

Comment: I agree...best to stick with the battle-tested code in this case

Comment: This is still unmanaged GDAL under the hood. In this particular case I am looking for managed only.

Comment: @BjartN: You can always use System.Drawing.Bitmap.PropertyItems, then handle processing the GeoTiff tags yourself: http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/spec/geotiff2.6.html#2.6.1   However, I'd rather use a managed wrapper around a native library...

Comment: Thx this might be what I am looking for. I will investigate :) Also, I might end up with a managed wrapper, but I'm not very keen on taking a dependency on GDAL. Would prefer something more lightweight.

Answer (score 4):

You won't see many in managed C#, due to the performance and memory usage limitation imposed by the .NET Framework memory management layer.  Don't get me wrong -- I love C# and .NET.  However, native C++ is much faster and (in my opinion) less frustrating to write, in this case.

Surveys typically contain many GeoTIFF files, which requires a lot of memory and manipulation of data, when performing geotransforms (i.e. WGS82 to UTMM to TIFF X-Y coordinate, and then back again.)  Demand for memory performance and management efficiency increases further, when you involve things like compiling results of linear, radial, and area surveys.

You probably don;t want to hear this, but writing a parser in native C++ and then wrapping it into C# is going to greatly increase performance and eliminate memory limitations.  Writing a parser is actually pretty easy, and will be very lightweight, as you can tailor it to your needs.  You will find this particularly true, when integrating more advanced features, such as automatic selection and spanning of GeoTIFF files.

Comment: I give you a point for the value add :)

Comment: Much appreciated!  ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about [this bit of code](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid91819AC578152EF910BD5976882B0209CDE9C334.aspx?s=geotiff#L46)?

Comment: This is unmanaged GDAL under the hood as well

Comment: The link is now no longer accessible